# How does one analyze this graph on atmospheric C02 data obtained from the Mauna Loa observatory?

Tags: climate-change, homework, co2

Graph I am analyzing:
[image]

What I am trying to figure out from the graph is:

- What is the range for CO<sub>2</sub> over the record (approximation)
- What are the major forcings for the overall trend in this record
- What is the range for CO<sub>2</sub> over a typical annual cycle (approximation)
- What are at least wo key properties of the physical geography of the Earth that contribute to these cycles?

Comment: Especially given the last question point, this appears to be a homework request.  We ask that you show your initiative towards answering these questions, tell us what YOU'RE thinking, and then perhaps we may be able to give input.  It benefits neither us nor you for us to just give answers.  Give it a try :)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest I was thinking that the for the last one, for physical geography I was thinking  how the seasons are different in different parts of the world and how that has some effect. Also, the oceans. But not sure how to expand that out.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest Also for range for C02 over the record I am thinking (280, 380) or a 100 unit range.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest As for the second question, as I understand the word forcings, it has to do with the amount of energy we receive from the sun, and the amount of energy we radiate back into space. Therefore some forcings that could influence this trend are deforestation therefore changing the albedo of earth (sun reflectivity). Another is human induced changes with greenhouse gases. And lastly since this is Hawaii one may consider atmospheric aerosols (volcanic sulfates)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest not sure about the range for C02 over a typical annual cycle, a one year span? it seems to be different every decade and keeps increasing, nothing typical.

Comment: @yre: For the last point about physical geography, think about changing seasons and land distribution in northern & southern hemispheres.

Comment: Two words: Keeling Curve.

Comment: @yre, sorry, yesterday got very busy. Think you should edit your thinking into the question itself, as a section below it perhaps. But you're definitely making good progress, and you should see answer soon. I think in this case they're using the word forcings in a general sense... to ask what's producing the changes (rather than it having anything particularly to do with energy, which indeed can be the meaning in a subset of thermodynamic type questions). The one-year cycles are the squiggly lines (the other is the annual cycle smoothed out).  The squiggles are around the same size throughout.